# Why does visual studio think js file is a cs file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a ASP.NET solution in Visual Studio 2008 and I added a file identical to http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt named jquery.cookie.js in a subfolder of my project containing other javascript files and Visual Studio is treating it as a C# file, giving me errors like `CS1012: Too many characters in character literal` and `Semicolon after method or accesssor block is not valid.`

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. I accidentally had `runat="server"` on one of the `<script>` tags that included the file.  I guess that caused it to try to compile

Answer (score 0):

Open the .js file properties in Visual Studio and make sure that Build Action is Content or None, but not Compile.

Comment: The only two properties listed is File Name and Full Path (readonly).  Maybe because it is setup as a website not a web project?